# How to add permanent route with Netmask?

Tags: subnet

I am  new to linux. I want to add below permanent route:

```
[root@Docker1 ~]# route -n | grep 10.246.179.0
10.246.179.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I added a file named route-eth0 in network-scripts as below:

```
10.246.179.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

But instead of 255.255.255.192, I am getting route as below:

```
10.246.179.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0   U   0    0     0    eth0
```

What should I do to get the desired result? I am on RHEL 6.

Comment: Dude...that's not linux specific. Would you please check your CIDR notation and netmask and _maybe_ find the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are providing a /24 netmask, which results in .0.

There are several subnet calculators available on the internet, you can use any one of them to get that the correct netmask for .192 is /26.

```
10.246.179.0/26 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

Comment: Oh it works like this. Thanks.